# platform_device structure member update

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am going through a platform driver's probe function. A `platform_device` structure pointer is passed as an argument to the probe function. Can you help to understand who will create this `platform_device` structure and fill the details in the structure. I am specifically looking for who will fill the resources, because in the probe function the memory resource was read using `platform_get_resource()` API. so trying to understand who will fill the memory resources in the `platform_device` structure and in which order the memory resources will be filled in the `platform_device` structure.

Comment: On a system using a devicetree, most of the platform devices will be populated by `of_platform_default_populate_init()`. On older embedded platforms they were filled in by board-specific code in the kernel. On a system using ACPI, there are various places in the kernel that call `acpi_create_platform_device()`.